# Javascript xlink:href local svg image

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble rendering an svg image stored in my local directory via js.
when I use a link to a website, the image is displayed correctly.
Here is a link to the code of the image : http://jsfiddle.net/am8ZB/

But when I use a local image nothing is displayed.

My code :

```
 d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);

var g = svg.append("g");

g.append("svg:image")
.attr("xlink:href", "manaz/src/label/flower_blue.svg")
.attr("width", 200)
.attr("height", 200)
.attr("x", 228)
.attr("y",53);
```

Here is the link where I downloaded it : https://publicdomainvectors.org/fr/gratuitement-des-vecteurs/Image-vectorielle-fleur-bleue/1992.html

Comment: Fairly sure the browser will be complaining about this. Any errors/warnings in the browser's developer console.

Comment: GET http://localhost:8082/manaz/src/label/flower_blue.svg
Status :404 Not Found

Comment: And is `[project directory]/manaz/src/label/flower_blue.svg` a proper path to that asset? If you try opening that link you pasted, with your server running, will you get that svg file?

Comment: Come across this recently myself and appeasr to be a security issue. The browser is blocking access to Cross-Domain XML - each request to local files is a separate domain. Are you running locally from a web server or just the file system.

Comment: @PLW when I copy and paste the link on a new page, the page sends me back Cannot GET /manaz/src/label/flower_blue.svg

Comment: @phuzi I use a local server that yarn created so when I modify my Js file, my localhost updates automatically

Comment: Looks like your URL is not right have you tried variations of it? e.g. http://localhost:8082/label/flower_blue.svg

Comment: @phuzi I just tried your link and it gives me the same error

Comment: You should experiment, it's almost certainly bad URL, if it gives you 404 when trying to access it manually. Try to change your src in line 8 to `./label/flower_blue.svg`, or `/label/flower_blue.svg`, or `./manaz/label/flower_blue.svg` etc., just experiment with it a little bit, something should work eventually.

Comment: All right, thanks, I'll do some tests and come back to you when I've found the solution.